# EntityCommandExecutionException, Schema not found

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, postgresql-9.1

I get the following error message:

ERROR:3F000: Schema Auto doesn't exists

I use a connectionstring in my `Web.config` and the database do contains the `Auto` Schema. Npgqsl is the provider i use. I didn't have this problem while using Oracle database 6 months ago.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the .edmx file and generated it again. Now it works.